# How can Smalltalk codes in Squeak be automatically indented?

Tags: indentation, smalltalk, squeak

I was wondering if Squeak has some automatic  indentation function to
make codes in disorder become clean and well-indented in a flash, just
like what we can do in VIM and MS VISUAL STUDIO.

Any good methods to make that happen ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an auto indent on new line preference:

[image: Preference Browser Screenshot with auto indent on new line hightlighted]

And you can pretty-print a method from the shift-click popup menu:
[image: System Browser with shift-menu open]

Moreover, you can automatically have each method pretty-printed upon viewing it by clicking on the rounded "source" button on the far right of the button ribbon in the System Browser. But beware that the pretty-printing does not always make the code actually prettier than the way as it was saved.